# Downloading the latest .NET Runtime programmatically

Tags: .net, .net-core

How can I download the latest .NET runtime programmatically, for some specific major version and for some platform?

Is there a link, something like dot.net/runtime/5/windows-x64-desktop/latest? (I completely made that up.)

Or are there NuGet packages containing the installers? Or something else?

Comment: If you need that to deploy an application, you could create a self-contained executable instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like `dotnet-install` is what you're after

```
./dotnet-install.sh --channel LTS
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

Comment: Kind of, but I'm not sure: It downloads and immediately unpacks a non-admin installation: "Note that the intended use of this script is for Continuous Integration (CI) scenarios".

Comment: @Martin What is your use case? You haven't mentioned it

Comment: Actually `dotnet-install` is a good starting point. It seems to me that one can get the installer simply by taking the download URL computed by the script and replacing `.zip` by `.exe` (or whatever). However, it seems to me this goes into the direction “currently working, but might stop working tomorrow”, and because it became a little too time consuming for me, I didn’t investigate further.